# Design Document for MongDB with Json style Did not produce the result object?

Tags: json, mongodb

This is my testing case for design a english-khmer document dictionary.

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    $json ='{
                              "word": "think",
                              "khmer" : 
                                    [
                                           {
                                                    "type":["Verb — past tense: thought ; past participle: thought ; present participle: thinking ; "] , 
                                                    "meaning": 
                                                        [
                                                            "(INTRANSITIVE) (to believe, to judge, to form or have in the mind, to determine, to use the mind in order to come to decisions, to anticipate; to call, to mind; to imagine, to conceive, to surmise) គិត, ពិចារណា, រិះគិត, ទ្រង់ព្រះតំរិះ, ទ្រង់ព្រះចិន្ដា",
                                                            "(TECHNICAL) គិតមានចេតនា​ឬផែនការរំពឹង", 
                                                        ],
                                            }
                                    ]
                              "english" : 
                                      [
                                        {
                                             "type":["Noun — Plural: Thinks"],
                                             "meaning" : 
                                                    [
                                                        "Act of thinking; a thought.",
                                                    ],
                                        }
                                        {
                                            "type": ["Verb — past tense: thought ; past participle: thought ; present participle: thinking ; "],
                                            "meaning"
                                                    [
                                                              "(TRANSITIVE) To seem or appear; -- used chiefly in the expressions methinketh or methinks, and methought.",
                                                              "(TRANSITIVE) To employ any of the intellectual powers except that of simple perception through the senses; to exercise the higher intellectual faculties.",
                                                    ],
                                         }
                                      ],
                              "other" :{
                                          "meaning":  [
                                                            "To presume, to venture",
                                                            "To conceive, to imagine",
                                                            ],
                                          "synonyms":[],
                                          "antonyms":[],
                                          "phrasalVerbs" :
                                                        [
                                                          "Think about",
                                                          "Think of",
                                                        ],
                                          "relatedPhrases" :
                                                            [
                                                              "think again",
                                                              "think ahead",
                                                            ],
                                        },
            }';

    $data = json_decode($json);
     echo "<pre>";
    print_r($data);
    echo "</pre>";        
    ?>
```

When I try to run this script I did not get the output like json Object.

Anyone Could help me about what is the problem with my Json String? or Json Design here ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a lot of errors in your JSON, I'd use a site like http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ to help you track down and fix them ...

You can see an example of some of the errors in your JSON below, but you'll need to visit the site and paste your JSON in to validate the whole thing.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much Justin Jenkins for the link,I use this to correct my invalid Json document design,It help me now.:)